# JSON filtering with live search

Tags: json, url, search, filter

I want to display data cards on a website. The data is retrieved from a JSON URL. It also works. But now I want to filter the cards so that I only see those that match the search input. Can someone help me?
I've tried several approaches, but can't get any further, because I'm also a beginner in Javascript.

I have the following code:

```js
var yourUrl = "myURL";
function Get(yourUrl) {
    // get JSON data via Ajax...
    return `[
    {"link": "alice", "profile": "profile1", "profilename": "Alice", "str": "Allen Street", "location": "New York"},
    {"link": "bob", "profile": "profile2", "profilename": "Bob", "str": "Market St.", "location": "San Francisco"}
    ]`;
}        
var postData = JSON.parse(Get(yourUrl));

function append_json(data) {
  //Set Up the template
  var s = $("#postTemplate")[0].innerHTML.trim();
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.innerHTML = s;
  var template = holder.childNodes;

  var member = document.getElementById('newprofile');
  data.forEach(function(object) {

    //Clone Template
    var newItem = $(template).clone();

    //Populate it
    $(newItem).find(".memurl").attr("href", object.link);
    var img = $(newItem).find(".thumb")
    $(img).attr("src", object.image).attr("alt", $(img).attr("alt") + object.profile + " " + "etc")
      .attr("title", $(img).attr("title") + object.profilename + " finish this off");
    $(newItem).find(".profile").html(object.profile);
    $(newItem).find(".street").html(object.str);
    $(newItem).find(".location").html(object.location);
    //Append it

    $(".newprofile").append(newItem);

  });
}

$("document").ready(function() {
  append_json(postData);
});
```

```css
.member {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="profilesearch">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
</div>

<div class="newprofile">
  <!-- Template for our posts -->
  <script type="text/template" id="postTemplate">
    <div class="member">
      <a class="memurl" href="">
        <img class="thumb" alt="Profil" title="Profil" src="">
       </a>
      <!-- Replaced p  with div, can't nest p tags -->
      <div class="info">
        <p class="profile"></p>
        <p class="street"></p>
        <p class="location"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-outmore">
      <a class="memurl" href="" target="_blank">Zum Profil</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: The most important question is - do you want to search on the server or on the client? Searching on the server is typically simpler and more efficient, because the server will only return matching records and the client can simply render them exactly as they come, However, it requires that you have a database of some sort and not just a flat text file with some JSON. Searching on the client is only viable for very small data sets.

Comment: The data comes from a database. So the search on the server would be the best I think.

Comment: That's a good plan. There are many examples of how to send a text box value to the server via jQuery Ajax, you should start there. Tips: 1) Use jQuery Ajax instead of the low-level `XMLHttpRequest`. 2) Use GET-requests. 3) Set a `Cache-Control` header on the server's response that prevents client-side caching. 4) On the server, if you're using an SQL database, **do not** build SQL by piecing together strings. Use parameters.

Comment: That being said, your question is too broad. Answering it would involve writing client-side *and* server-side code, none of which even exists yet, in order to build a complete system from scratch. That's out of scope for a question on this site. So maybe it's a good approach to start with the tips I wrote down and work forward step by step. Each of those individual things have been described in numerous posts on this site.